# How can i reduce precision only on the maximum value of a column matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, decimal

I would like to reduce the precision only to the maximum value of my matrix D3. All the values are with 4 decimals but i want the maximum with only two decimals, rounded down. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You forgot to include your sample matrix. Please also include your desired results and what you've tried so far.

Comment: round function can take a second argument specifying how many numbers you want after the decimal point.

Comment: @Navan: round() rounds to nearest. You need floor() to "round down" as the OP wants.

Comment: @Scott you are right. Did not read "rounded down".

Answer (score 0):

```
floor(max(max(D3))*100)/100
```

if you want to avoid displaying the extra zeros at the end, use fprintf:

```
fprintf('%4.2f\n',floor(max(max(D3))*100)/100)
```

if you want to alter the value in the matrix to reflect that change in precision:

```
[val,loc] = max(D3(:));
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(D3),loc);
D3(r,c) = floor(val*100)/100;
```

Comment: Hi @L.Scott Johnson and really thanks for your reply. I tryed the code but i don't see the value altered in the matrix. It seems to be like before (52.3900 and not 52.38). Can you help me again? Thanks

Comment: D3 = [27.1012    
         15.4221
         26.5106
         52.3900
         15.8544 ]                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                         
These are some of the numbers i have in the matrix D3. The maximum is 52.3900 and i want to have 52.38. It is a matrix formed by 1 column and n rows... sorry but i don't know hot to upload it here.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. 52.3900 rounded down to 2 decimal places is 52.39, not 52.38

Comment: If you want to also subtract 0.01 from that value, that should be trivial enough.

Comment: i don't know, it gives me 52.38, but in the first part of the code (fprintf('%4.2f\n',floor(max(max(D3))*100)/100)). If i try the substitution in the matrix, it doesn't give me the new value (52.38), but still the older one (52.3900). Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: @Elisam You're going to have to show us what you're talking about. Please add a [mcve] to your question including a *small* sample matrix and the results you expect from that matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @beaker. That's what i've done in the previous comments no?

Comment: @Elisam Why would `52.3900` round to `52.38`? Are you trying to change the values, or just the way they're displayed? What does your comment about "substitution in the matrix" mean? If you edited your question and clearly demonstrated what results you expect for your `D3` matrix (or any other sample you choose) it might help us to understand better what you're asking.

Comment: @Elisam You say "it gives me 52.38". But both math and Matlab "give" 52.39 for the input (at least so far as we can determine the input, since you haven't given the input explicitly). To verify, type this in Matlab: `fprintf('%.2f\n', 52.3900)` and see that the output is 52.39. Please edit your question with a complete **minimal** Matlab code that creates D3 (with, say, 3 values), and say exactly what outcome you are looking for (a displayed number, an updated set of values in D3, or whatever).